# jCarouselLite não funciona

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo não funciona. O jCarouselLite não funciona, apesar de esse mesmo code estar funcionando em outro site que fiz.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $(".itens"). jCarouselLite({
                btnPrev: '.prev', 
                btnNext: '.next',
                visible: 4
            })
        })
        </script>

<div class="itens">

                <ul class="itens-para-add">

                    <li class="item-individual">

                        <div class="img-ind">
                            <a href=""><img src="img/Tela01.png"></a>
                        </div>

                    </li><!-- INDIVIDUAL -->

                    <li class="item-individual">


                        <div class="img-ind">
                            <a href=""><img src="img/Tela02.png"></a>
                        </div>

                    </li><!-- INDIVIDUAL -->

                    <li class="item-individual">

                        <div class="img-ind">
                            <a href=""><img src="img/Tela03.png"></a>
                        </div>

                    </li><!-- INDIVIDUAL -->

                    <li class="item-individual">

                        <div class="img-ind">
                            <a href=""><img src="img/Tela04.png"></a>
                        </div>

                    </li><!-- INDIVIDUAL -->

                    <li class="item-individual">

                        <div class="img-ind">
                            <a href=""><img src="img/Tela05.png"></a>
                        </div>

                    </li><!-- INDIVIDUAL -->

                    <li class="item-individual">

                        <div class="item-title">
                            <h1>Camiseta Imagine em SP</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div class="img-ind">
                            <a href=""><img src="img/pulseira.jpg"></a>
                        </div>

                    </li><!-- individual -->

                </ul><!-- ITENS PARA ADD -->

                    <nav class="menu-carrossel">
                        <a href="#" class="prev btn-scroll" title="Anterior"><</a>
                        <a href="#" class="next btn-scroll" title="Próximo">></a>
                    </nav>


                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!-- ITENS PARA ADD  -->
```

Comment: Apois, estão todas na referida pasta "img", estão exibindo corretamente, o arquivo js do carrossel está devidamente linkado bem como o do jquery, porém não funcniona.

Comment: Insira na pergunta informações relevantes, como a ordem de carregamento das bibliotecas e as respectivas versões, se está usando algum outro plugin junto e o que for necessário mais. E também se mostra erros no console. Isso evita que se perca tempo aqui nos comentários solicitando essas informações e vc corre o risco de obter uma resposta mais precisa e muito mais rapidamente.